# Symfony 1.4 jobeet tutorial day 3 I can't make it work together

Tags: symfony-1.4, jobeet

I have executed successfully - at least I could not detect any error messages - all the commands that were prompted in a tutorial I'm following, but when I try and test it on the browser, I can only display a rough table with no stylesheets or buttons or menus whatsoever.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Incidentally, in order to troubleshoot the problem I have tried to hack the code adding manually on the address bar some actions, and when I forced `frontend_dev.php/job/new`, I got some form, that is encouraging.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Of course there must be something wrong but I can't work it out apparently; I have done the same procedure several times and I am starting to feel a little discouraged, can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just make command

```
   $ php symfony plugin:publish-assets
```

p.s don't waste your time on symfony 1.4, try learn symfony2 ;-)